# Chebychev Polynomial derivatives at zero points and extreme points

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, approximation, polynomials, chebyshev

I was looking for some help with derivatives of Chebychev polynomials at zero points. The recursive expression,

$$
T_{(j+1)}(x) = 2xT_j(x) - T_{(j-1)}(x)
$$

has the derivative 
$$
T'_{j+1}(x) = 2T_j(x) + 2xT'_j(x) - T'_{j-1}(x)
$$

with $T'_0=0$ and $T'_1=1$.

But I was looking at Trefethen's book (Chapter 6, Page 54) where he uses the following code to construct a derivative matrix for Chebychev polynomials at extreme points:

```
% CHEB compute D = differentiation matrix, x = Chebyshev grid 
function [D,x] = cheb(N) 
if N==0, D=0; x=1; return, end 
x = cos(pi*(0:N)/N)'; 
c = [2; ones(N-1,1); 2].*(-1).^(0:N)'; 
X = repmat(x,1,N+1); 
dX = X-X'; 
D = (c*(1./c)')./(dX+(eye(N+ 1))) ; % off-diagonal entries 
D = D - diag(sum(D'));
```

How are these two derivative calculations related? Or is it that the derivatives at extreme points and zero points are calculated differently, as above? Any references I can read to better understand this?

Thank you.

Comment: One is the derivative in physical space, and the other in spectral space. It is quite similar to performing a [derivative in Fourier space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation) (with the difference that in your case the derivative operator is not diagonal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On p. 53 of the book of Trefethen, you can read 
"D_{N} contains the derivative of the degree N polynomial interpolant p_j(x) to the delta function supported at x_j [= cos(j*pi/N)], sampled at the grid {x_i}"
So the entries of D are the derivatives of the Lagrange interpolatory polynomials and not the Chebyshev polynomials.